# How to get specific column value in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, sqldatareader

I have a sql query which gives result as

```
Column 1   : Column 2
-350000    : -349000
-217500    : -565500
```

I am trying to just get the value of `2nd Column` of `2nd Row`

which is  `-565500`

Please tell me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways, for example:

Using a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("Sql-Query", con))
    da.Fill(table);
object secondRowSecondColumnValue = table.Rows[1][1];
```

If you know that it's an `int`:

```
int value = table.Rows[1].Field<int>(1);
```

---

Using a `SqlDataReader` is less concise:

```
int? value = null;
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Sql-Query", con))
{
    con.Open();
    int row = 0;
    using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            row++;
           if (row == 2)
           {
               value = rd.GetInt32(1);
               break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you only want that value the best option is to select only this value in the first place.